# VB Form1 cannot see Dialog1

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Using Visual Studio 2019
Accidently renamed Form1 instead of a TextBox and then renamed it Form1.
Have Form1.vb and Form1.Designer.vb

Created a Dialog1, but VS says that it has not been shared.

```
        Dialog1.errLabel.Text = "Please enter a full TN"
        Dialog1.Show()
        Dialog1.TopMost = True
```

Comment: What does it actually say, verbatim? Does it actually say something along the lines of "access to a non-Shared member requires an instance"? Please copy and paste the actual error message rather than a vague and misleading approximation.

Comment: By the way, you should configure a form before showing it, so `TopMost` should be set before `Show` is called. It won't make much, if any, real difference in this case but it may in others.

Answer (score -1):

create code

```
 If InputBox("please enter your name", "name") = "name" Then
        TextBox1.ReadOnly = False
       Else
        TextBox1.ReadOnly = True
         End If
```